# Problem with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

This works :

```
alert(document.getElementById("Container").nodeName);
```

But this doesnt :

```
var CurParent = document.getElementById("Container");
alert(CurParent.nodeName);
```

I am using IE7.
Why ?

Comment: Uhh ... I'm not sure I believe that.  When you say it "doesn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: Both snippets are equivalent. The problem is elsewhere. Why do you think the second one doesn't work? Are the HTML documents exactly the same otherwise?

Comment: Here's a thing to note: IE will return elements from that routine based on "id" *or* "name" value.

Comment: Works for me. As Ayman Hourieh suggests, look elsewhere.

Comment: Not working, The syntax#1 works in both IE and Firefox. Second one doesnt. I am mixing jquery and javascript.

Comment: I was using a global variable like :
var parent = document.body;
and making the alert call from within the function. 
When I put both in the function, it works.
Any reason ?

Comment: Working sample, please? It doesn't make sense that this would be the problem, so a full demonstration of an HTML document where it works as you report would be extremely helpful.

Comment: What Matchu says. The code you are showing is not the code showing the symptoms you describe. How should one tell the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your latest comment, this seems to be an issue with variable scoping. Are you sure that the var `parent` is *really* global? The following will **not** work, due to improper variable scope:

```
function firstThing() {
    var parent = document.body;
}

function secondThing() {
    return parent;
}

firstThing();
secondThing(); // will return undefined
```

Define a variable in the largest scope where you intend to use it. The following **will** work.

```
var parent;

function firstThing() {
    parent = document.body;
}

function secondThing() {
    return parent;
}

firstThing();
secondThing(); // will return document.body
```

Comment: you are right. but var parent = document.body; // doesnt, if declared and initialized globally.

Comment: Not sure what that comment means. I'm pretty sure that, if you do a `var parent = whatever` declaration in a different scope, like inside a function, it still has no effect on the larger-scoped variable, because you used the `var` keyword.